# jquery-ui: how to set the class name in the selectmenu item (option)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a `<select>` form in which a unique class is set for one option:

```
<select id='mylist'>
    <option value = '1'>One</option>
    <option value = '2' class='my_element'>Two</option>
</select>
```

When I connect `selectmenu`

```
$('#mylist').selectmenu();
```

Class in new `selectmenu` object disappears (does not appear)

```
<li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Two</div></li>
```

How to fix it? I want

```
<li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper my_element">Two</div></li>
```

OR

```
<li class="ui-menu-item my_element"><div id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Two</div></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite [_renderMenu()](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-_renderMenu):

```js
$('#mylist').selectmenu().data("ui-selectmenu")._renderMenu = function(ul, items) {
    var that = this;
    items.forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        var li = that._renderItemData(ul, ele);
        if (ele.element.get(0).classList.length>0) {
            // preserve original classes...
            li.addClass(ele.element.get(0).classList.value);
        }
    });
};
```

```css
.my_element {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select id='mylist'>
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2' class='my_element'>Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery-ui `.selectmenu()` we can specify additional classes to add to the widget's elements.

You may find code example at their [documentation here.](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#option-classes)

Hope this helps.

Comment: not work :(
checked all native jquery-ui classes


    classes: {
    "ui-selectmenu-button-closed": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-button": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-text": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-icon": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-menu": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-open": "my_element",
    "ui-selectmenu-optgroup": "my_element",
    "ui-menu-item": "my_element",
    },